# Evidence for and against (verbal-IQ-based) Smart Fraction Theory

Tags: economics, intelligence

Currently Smart Fraction Theory is subject of some discussion among the economists. The theory holds that the wealth of the country is heavily impacted by the *fraction* of the population that has IQ above certain threshold.

The following article adds another twist to it: it uses *verbal* IQ as threshold as it is argued it seems to account for East Asian GDP per capita lower than it would seem from using raw IQ numbers.

http://www.lagriffedulion.f2s.com/sft2.htm

I'm looking for solid (empirical) evidence that tends to support or reject this theory.

Comment: That link's format as a conversation of some kind is weird. This looks like it would be very technically involved to address fully, I'm unclear how they recalibrate verbal IQ measures across different languages (if you don't it's meaningless) and I'd guess that the correlation with countries simply having good school systems would confound everything terribly. I'm not sure this belongs here rather than on the Economics Stack Exchange